# ASP.Net MVC SQL Formatting HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a SQL table that contains HTML formatting for text shown.

`<strong>What Is EDI ?</strong><p>EDI is a method for communicating electronically with trading partners based upon standards.</p>`

Within my MVC application there is an index.cshtml page below:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Body)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

The problem is that the text is appearing as normal with no HTML formatting. Can anybody help to fix the issue I am having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [@Html.Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) for this purpose.

Instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)
```

Use

```
@Html.Raw(item.Body)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980657/display-string-as-html-in-asp-net-mvc-view).