# Get string from PartialViewResult WITHOUT .ControllerContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I render a `string` with HTML code from `PartialViewResult` **WITHOUT having to use `ControllerContext`** 
(because in my controller object .ControllerContext is `null`, and making fakes nor trying to hack it wasn't working. .ControllerContext isn't `null` from **INSIDE** of Contorller, but I need to use it **OUTSIDE** of this Contorller).

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model) {
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

(broader explaination)--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have tried:

1. making fakes
2. trying to call it from anther Controller (success, but I dont have specific .cshtml inside this controller)
3. trying to make non-null ControllerContext in various, even most stupid ways
4. just trying to "make plain string" from this `PartialViewResult` (.ToString())
5. Even copy-paste code from 1 Controller to 2nd Controller. It won't work, because I got these controller objects from DependencyRegistrar (IoC), and then I ofc can use them, **but they always have null .ControllerContext.**

I just have `PartialViewResult` from some `ActionResult` method that have 100% valid and working HTML code. 
I had done a hard search toward this topic, but all I found were answers that use ControllerContext (btw. THIS piece 
of code is mentioned on at least 20 different websities. I also have this in my project and I have to say, it 
works excellent, but I have a `PartialViewResult` outside controller).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display string as html in asp.net mvc view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980657/display-string-as-html-in-asp-net-mvc-view)

Comment: Why don't you make the method into an action result and just return the partial view?

Comment: I need HTML code as string to return it as Json object (for AJAX). I can't modify source code (so I have non-null .ControllerContext) - I can modify only an extension of source code.

Comment: Have you tried loading your partial with AJAX? You can easily call your partial page using AJAX, the partial page will render thru the controller and the data will be the complete HTML that you want. Maybe I don't understand what you need, but this method has worked for me many times. If this is what you want, I can write up an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class **ActionFilterAttribute** constains a method OnActionExecuted() with one argument of type **ActionExecutedContext**  and name filterContext.

Yes, **filterContext already contains initialized and valid .ControllerContext that I was missing.**

This attribute can be atached directly to controller, action (only these that returns ActionResult) or indirectly via inheriting IFilterProvider with its one method GetFiltres

```
public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
{
    if ((actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(GemStoneProject.GemStoneController)) &&
        (actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("GemStoneAction")) && controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        return new List<Filter>() { new Filter(this, FilterScope.Action, 0) };
    }

    return new List<Filter>() { };
}


    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    /*your code, that replaces previous View to new View. 
You have available and valid .ControllerContext inside "filterContext" argument*/
    }
```

You will need also this line, if you want to all 
builder.RegisterType().As();

Effect: after execution of GemStoneAction, the OnActionExecuted will be called. **With valid .ControllerContext of GemStoneController.**